# Construction of an holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, f(z)=\cos(z)$. I am looking for a biholomorphic function $\varphi:U\rightarrow V$ with $U,V$ neighbourhoods of $0$ so that $f(z)=f(0)+(\varphi(z))^2$ for all $z\in U$.

I have tried to work with the Taylorseries but that didn't help. I also have no idea how to choose $U$ and $V$.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Use a trigonometric identity on $1 - \cos z$. $\varphi$ drops out almost immediately.

Comment: What identity do you mean? $\cos(z)-1=-2\sin(z/2)^2$? So then $\varphi(z)=i\sqrt{2}\sin(z/2)$? And what about $U,V$? $U=V=\mathbb{C}$? Is that $\varphi$ biholomorphic?

Comment: Indeed, that identity. Thus we have an entire function $\varphi_0$ such that $f(z) = f(0) + (\varphi_0(z))^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Now, given any connected neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, there are precisely two holomorphic functions $\varphi \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z) = f(0) + (\varphi(z))^2$ for all $z \in U$, namely the restriction $\varphi_0\lvert_U$ and its negative. Clearly $\varphi_0$ is not biholomorphic (it has period $4\pi$, so is not injective), thus it remains to find a neighbourhood $U$ on which $\varphi_0$ is injective, and then set $V = \varphi_0(U)$.

Comment: There are of course many possible choices of $U$. The smaller you choose $U$, the easier it is to prove injectivity of $\varphi_0$ on $U$. But the mapping properties of $\sin$ are relatively simple, so it's not too hard to find a simple $U$ on which $\varphi_0$ is injective that is also maximal (in the sense that if $U_1$ is an open set with $U \subsetneqq U_1$, then $\varphi_0\lvert_{U_1}$ is not injective).

Comment: Tank you :) Can I define $U=B_{2\pi}(0)$? What is the easiest coice of $U$?

Comment: $B_{2\pi}(0)$ doesn't work, we have $\varphi_0(2\pi - z) = \varphi_0(z)$. $B_{\pi}(0)$ would work. The easiest choice of $U$ is a disk (or a rectangle if you prefer) on which $\bigl\lvert 1 - \frac{1}{2}\cos \frac{z}{2}\bigr\rvert < 1$. A simple maximal $U$ is the strip $\{ z : \lvert \operatorname{Re} z\rvert < \pi\}$.

Comment: But $2\pi$ is not in $B_{2\pi}(0)$. Why would your strip work and what is the image?

Comment: $2\pi \notin B_{2\pi}(0)$, right. But $1\in B_{2\pi}(0)$ and $2\pi - 1 \in B_{2\pi}(0)$. To see why the strip works and what the image is, look at the two maps $z \mapsto e^{iz/2}$, and $w \mapsto (w - 1/w)$. Up to multiplication with a constant, their composition is $\varphi_0$.

Comment: I do not see why that strip works. Why is $\varphi_0$ injective on that strip?